# Get summary stats for nested dataframes within a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes where I would like to return the summary stats for each of the dataframes within that list into a new dataframe - able to choose the column (values) within each of the initial dataframes to return the summary stats. Each row in the output dataframe corresponding to each dataframe in the initial list.

I am able to get the summary stats output using a for-loop, but it will only give me the summary stats for the last dataframe within my list - not all of the dataframes in the list. Here is a sample of the for-loop that gives me output stats on the last dataframe within the list.

```
for i in step2:
    step3=i.describe() #gives me a single df of the last item (dataframe) in my list
```

Here is what my list looks like:
[image]

I would like each row in the output dataframe corresponding to the summary stats of chosen columns (values) within the dataframes on the initial list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest variant:

```py
step3 = []
for i in step2:
    step3.append(i.describe())
```

Here you will get a list of summary DataFrames.

A more complex one:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in step2:
    df_result = df_result.append(i.describe().T)
```

Each row in your output DataFrame will correspond to a column (with transposing as in the example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([i.describe() for i in step2])
```

Or loop by each DataFrame, append to list and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
step3 = []
for i in step2:
    step3.append(i.describe())

df = pd.concat(step3)
```